# How to generate moving weighted average in SQL with custom weights?

Tags: sql

I am trying to generate weighted window average of each row in a table by considering two preceeding row values. I could generate window average the rows. But I couldn't find a method to do a weighted window average.

The table is as below:

```sql
create table T (idx int, key_val char(1), ts int, value int);
insert into T
values 
(1    , 'a'   , 0    , 20),
(1    , 'a'   , 0   , 30 ) , 
(1    , 'a'   , 300    , 30),
(1    , 'a'   , 300   , 40 ) ,
(1    , 'a'   , 600   , 40 ) , 
(1    , 'a'   , 600   , 50 ) , 
(1    , 'a'   , 900   , 60 ) , 
(1    , 'a'   , 900   , 50 ) , 
(1    , 'a'   , 1200   , 80 ) , 
(1    , 'a'   , 1200   , 60 ),
(1    , 'b'   , 0    , 20),
(1    , 'b'   , 0   , 20 ) , 
(1    , 'b'   , 300    , 30),
(1    , 'b'   , 300   , 30 ) ,
(1    , 'b'   , 600   , 40 ) , 
(1    , 'b'   , 600   , 40 ) , 
(1    , 'b'   , 900   , 50 ) , 
(1    , 'b'   , 900   , 50 ) , 
(1    , 'b'   , 1200   , 60 ) , 
(1    , 'b'   , 1200   , 60 ); 

SELECT * from T;
```

Script to generate the window average is as below:

```sql
select *,
  avg(value) OVER(ORDER BY idx, key_val, ts
     ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
     as moving_average
from T;
```

I wanted to do something like below:
`1.5* current_row_value + 0.5 * just_preceeding_row_value + 0.25 * 2nd_preceeding_row_value`

If we consider 3rd row, calculation will be looks like:

`30*1.5+30*0.5+20*0.25`

If we consider 4th row, calculation will be looks like:

`40*1.5+30*0.5+30*0.25`

Can anyone help me to modify my current script to generate weighted window average?

Weight can be hard coded or we can take from another table

Comment: Tag only a **single** RDBMS!

Comment: See [lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Single != none... The solution will depend on the exact RDBMS you are using

Comment: What would you do on rows 1 and 2? Did you know that `LAG` and `LEAD` accept an `offset` parameter?

Comment: @Charlieface: I found the solution with LAG concept. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @allmhuran: I found the solution with LAG concept. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `LAG` concept as below:

```sql
select *,
   (1.5*value + 0.5*(LAG(value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY idx, key_val, ts)) + 0.25*(LAG(value, 2)) OVER (ORDER BY idx, key_val, ts))/3 as weighted_window_average
from T;
```

Comment: Missing OVER clause for second LAG.